# LESS support on older android browser(2.* specific)

Tags: android, css, less

I am converting a website to responsive using media queries and less. I am compiling less on client side using js, but it doesn't support older Android browsers(2.X). Is there a fix for this?

Comment: precompile to css or don't use lesscss?

Comment: I wouldn't suggest compiling less on client side especially on mobile devices when you want your website as lightweight as possible.

Comment: Aside from the reasonable recommendation of not using client-side compilation, see [Browser Support](http://lesscss.org/usage/#browser-support) (i.e. most likely `es-5 shim` would make those browsers Less compatible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning to css is a good idea in this case: precompile the final version. You can use SimpleLESS or similar compiler to do it. Reducing client-side resources is healthy, especially for mobile/responsive UIs.

Comment: SimpLESS is quite outdated these days so it's not a good idea to recommend it in the first ranks. There's comprehensive [list](http://lesscss.org/usage/#guis-for-less) of the Less tools at the official site after all